# Store Object in PHP Session

Tags: php, oop, serialization

In PHP, is it considered best practice to store the complete object as a session variable?

From my experience, sometimes it works and sometime not. Is there any specific reason for it?

Example:

```
session_start();
$object = new sample_object();
$_SESSION['sample'] = $object;
```

Comment: It should work without problem if the object is serializable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `serialize()` in PHP before store your object, and call `unserialize()` when retrieve your object from session.

**store object**

```
session_start();
$object = new sample_object();
$_SESSION['sample'] = serialize($object);
```

**retrieve object**

```
session_start();
$object = unserialize($_SESSION['sample']);
```

Comment: And the `sample_object` class must be loaded before `unserialize`.

Comment: Yes, the `class` must be loaded before `unserialize()` the `object`

Answer (score 2):

In general, the best practice is not to store objects in session at all :D

I would recommend to instead just store data. It will have the added benefit of making the debugging process a bit easier, when you have to inspect the current state of the session.

If you want to be really fancy, you could make a separate [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), that stores and retrieves data from the session for instances of that specific class (or group of classes, with the same interface).

Comment: Then you lose out on retrieving a stored object with getters and setters - a nice structure that represents your data model. Manually storing data is fiddly and without structure. You have to ask the session class to get values from specific keys which have to be mapped somewhere. Mapping all the keys you store in the session could be abstracted out to some separate registry or whatever, but isn't this just crying out for an object class to map your properties and data types? Serializing and deserializing an object in and out of a session is painless.