# PHP Session not staying set

Tags: php, session

I am using Slim3 framework for routing. Other than that I have no frameworks.

My application starts in `index.php`

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/middleware.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php';

// Run app
$app->run();
```

As you can see, I quite clearly start a session before anything really happens.

In `routes.php` where all the action happens, I make a request to see if there is a `$_SESSION['user']` object. It is always `NULL` even though I am setting it. But I know why - because if I

`var_dump((session_status());exit;`

It is *always* = to `PHP_SESSION_NONE`.

If I look in my browser, I still have the same PHP session ID each time I refresh the page.

I don't know what to do. `session_start();` is not working.

---

I've added `session_start()` everywhere conceivable. Here is how I set the session in my User class. So it works. But when moving to another page, `$_SESSION['user']` is `NULL`

```
private function setSession(){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $this;
    // var_dump($_SESSION['user']);exit; // prints what you'd expect
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need that if statement ..  `if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)`  --  `session_start()` will not clear your session .. It simply instantiates it.   From what I can see in this limited view, you can remove the `if statement` and just use `session_start()`  --  Plus, I'd put `session_start()` in `settings.php` if it gets called on every page.

Comment: `session_start()` needs to be called on every page.  You're not going to have a session until you start it.  Only _after_ you start it (within the same request) would you see a change in the return value of `session_status()`

Comment: Yes @PatrickQ I do see the status change from NONE to ACTIVE. The problem is my USER is always NULL I guess.

Comment: Can you show where you're trying to use/fetch the saved value of `$_SESSION['user']`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store Object in PHP Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887880/store-object-in-php-session)

Comment: I think you got it @PatrickQ. There was a PDO object in there I suppose it does not like. THanks.